# How to add js in magento

Tags: javascript, magento, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to add following js to my magento site.

How can i add it?

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

and

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel();
  });
</script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 2000
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an xml update in your local.xml:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>path/to/script.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

The path is the relative path from magento_root/js/

Comment: it do not have any js files. its only have this scripts and urls

Comment: You can put your code in a js file in the js directory.

Comment: Also use `jQuery` instead of `$` to be certain.

Answer (score 1):

There is two way to include js file 
Create a local.xml in your  theme/layout/local.xml
 then use

```
<default>
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>path/to/script.js</script></action>
</reference>


</default>
```

or you can simple add js in your .phtml but it would give some conflicts and you can remove them by creating a js variable and passing that variable to your carousel js code

Answer (score 0):

dont forget to put jQuery into noConflict() mode as it will clash with Magento's native libraries.  Also I would recommend you dont use $ to declare jQuery in your script.  Instead, do something like this;

```
$jq = jQuery.noConflict();

$jq(document).ready(function() {

// do something

});
```